# WordPress & Plugin version not updating on amazon-ec2

Tags: amazon-ec2, permissions, wordpress

**I have a word press site in amazon ec2 instance.I am getting issue with installation and updating the plugin.**

**Issue:-**

1)When i try to install plugin from wp-admin backend.It's show the bellow error so that every time i need to upload the plugin manually on server and then need to activate from wp-admin backend.

```
Unpacking the package…
Could not create directory.
```

2)When i try to update plugin & wordpress from wp-admin backend.It's show the bellow error

```
 Update Plugin
 Downloading update from …
 Unpacking the update…
 Could not create directory.
```

**My word press file permission structure like bellow:-**

wp-content-> `"755"`

plugins-> `"755"`

plugins->e.g(captcha) `"755"`

and under the captcha plugin file i have-> `"664"` permission.

If have any body idea regarding this issue let me know.

the answer will be appreciated.

I have searched through the google but i didn't find any solution.

Comment: Did you set any restriction via .Htaccess?

Comment: Also once set permission 777 then try to update. Once update done then set permission to 755 back.

Comment: @Helping Hands i have solved my issue see my updated answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That mean issue here is that apache does not have access to the folders. The default permission is given to the ec2-user in the AMI.

run this in your terminal and you will be ready to go for update,install plugin and wordpress.

```
sudo chown -R apache:apache /var/www/html
```

In case when updating the plugin and word press if `wp-admin` asking for ftp credential just add the bellow snippet code in `wp-config` file .

```
define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');
```

and run the command.

```
sudo chown -R apache:apache /var/www/html
```

Comment: this also worked for me. I'm bothered though why setting it up with 777 priv wont work but setting the ownership will work